# Eclipse Plugin: Get the class name on user's click/selection

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an Eclipse Plugin. I am stuck in the part **where I need to get the class name as soon as the user selects/clicks on classname** in the package explorer and then I want to display it in a custom view. 
(Broadly I want to call API of another software in the custom view corresponding to that class name).
But I am not able to extract the class name on user's click. This feature is similar to the "Types" view, where corresponding class file appears in the view as soon as user clicks .java in the project explorer.  I am quite new to plugin development, please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: classname in the package explorer. thanks for correction @PeterRader

Comment: Are you writing a popup action for the package explorer?

Comment: Actually I want the classname as soon as the user clicks it and then display it in the custom view (can be any simple view) along with the other information that I will get from API call of another software. 
I want to use this feature of detection the user's click, so if you know about that in a popup action, then please share. I am sure it will also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the view:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IViewPart viewPart = page.findView(id);
```

The id for the Packages Explorer View is org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer

If the view is not open viewPart will be null.

Get the selection provider from the view site:

```
ISelectionProvider selProvider = viewPart.getSite().getSelectionProvider();
```

You can now use `addSelectionChangedListener` to listen for selection changes.

In the selection event `getSelection()` will normally return an instance of `IStructuredSelection` containing the current selections. Use `IStructuredSelection.iterator()` to iterate through the selection objects.

In the Packages Explorer View each selected object will be an object of a type such as `IProject` or `IFile` or perhaps something specific to the JDT code.

Comment: thanks. i used  System.out.println(event.getSelection().toString());
   and i am getting this string: .*******************************
[[Working copy] Activator.java [in testinnewwindow1 [in src [in testInnewWindow1]]]
  package testinnewwindow1
  import org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin
  import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext
  class Activator
    String PLUGIN_ID
    Activator plugin
    Activator()
    void start(BundleContext)
   **********************************
  
how can I parse this string. Is there any way? I only need classname: Activator.java &
project name: testinnewwindow1

Comment: Added a bit more to the answer about the selection.

Comment: ho greg-449, this program was working fine few days back. but now i got this ".NullPointerException" when i am trying to run "detectSelction" class in  a sampleview plugin. Please suggest?

Comment: @SrbNyk You need to ask a new question with the failing code and the stack trace

Comment: @greg-449..i posted the question, please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951044/i-am-facing-error-nullpointexeption-while-trying-to-detect-the-users-selecti

Answer (score 0):

The Package-Explorer is a Plugin depending on JDT Plugin is depending on .....

You must depend your plugin from the Package-Explorer-Plugin. On startup you must find the type-hierarchys extending-point where a type-hierarchy-registry creates new typehierarchy-View on demand, add your own click-listener and evaluate the result.

Not a work of a newbe in plugin-development. Have luck.

Comment: Yes, my plgin is depending on org.eclipse.jdt.ui and I already tried JavaUI class to get the information about the elemnet but unfortunately it was showing error in the findElementToSelect( IJavaElement.CLASS_FILE ) method.

Comment: findElementToSelect does not sounds to me like a listener-method. What a listener did you attach?